# How to add DOI to the published version of an article in arXiv?

Tags: journals, copyright, arxiv, doi, cross-referencing

I uploaded an article to arXiv which has been published in The Astrophysical Journal after referee suggested edits and final proof. How do I cross ref the arXiv version with the DOI of the published version? Do I just cross-ref the DOI of published version with the older version in arXiv or do I download the published pdf and upload it with DOI as a new version in arXiv? (I think the latter is not allowed as when I uploaded the published version of another paper as full-text on researchgate, I was told to remove it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Upload the revised version that you submitted to the journal (i.e. the one which got accepted finally). But, don't upload the post-produced pdf that you got from the publisher (and did not compile yourself from a `.tex`); this is not allowed by most journals. Further, you might want to look at the journal's statements about arXiv submissions. Some journals clearly mention this on their website. Your new submission to arXiv will be given some new version ID e.g arXiv:xxxx.yyyyy.v2
2. You can just edit your present arXiv article and edit the DOI field (please see https://arxiv.org/help/jref). Additionally, you can add a comment "For a revised version and its published version refer to the Journal of XYZ, DOI. cd/90111" (This option would not help you much if you want to make your revised version available for public; in case the journal is subscription-based).

Comment: I think using the journal template/logo is allowed; what is not allowed is using the post-produced pdf that you got from the publisher (did not compile yourself).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You are right. Few journals mention to not use their logo at least in my field (CS). Please feel free to edit my answer, to make it more correct. Thank you.

Comment: The arxiv has a dedicated field for the DOI.  You should add it there, ***not*** in a comment.

Answer (score 7):

The arxiv has a dedicated field where you can add the DOI.  (Note that this will not create a new version.)

In addition, most journals will allow you to upload the final accepted version (that is, the version with the corrections you did following the referee comments, but without any copyediting done by the journal), so you can additionally upload that version when you add the DOI (and potentially clarify in the "comments" field that this is the accepted version).

Answer (score 2):

[arXiv automatically ingests publication metadata](https://arxiv.org/help/bib_feed) from many journals and some other sources. So the DOI might be automatically updated for you once your article is published. For a major journal like ApJ, I would expect that to be the case.

If that turns out not to happen, then you can update the DOI and journal reference metadata on the version of the paper that you have uploaded. I believe it's generally understood that those metadata items refer to a final published version of the paper, whereas the PDF that can be downloaded from arXiv is a preprint, which *will not precisely match* the published version. You don't need to upload a new PDF to arXiv, but if there is a more updated version that you're allowed to upload, it's a nice courtesy to other researchers if you do so.

Comment: I'm thrilled.  For some reason, I've never seen this happen.